# How to pass arguments to NSAction?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uikit, uiviewanimation

Well, everyone knows that in ObjC we have

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Notice that `completion` block has a BOOL argument.
Now let's look at Monotouch:

```
public static void Animate (double duration, double delay, UIViewAnimationOptions options, NSAction animation, NSAction completion)
```

NSAction is:

```
public delegate void NSAction ();
```

Just the delegate without any arguments. Moreover, in Monotouch "internals" we can see:

```
public static void Animate (double duration, double delay, UIViewAnimationOptions options, 
NSAction animation, NSAction completion)
{
    UIView.AnimateNotify (duration, delay, options, animation, delegate (bool x)
    {
        if (completion != null)
        {
            completion ();
        }
    });
}
```

Notice `delegate (bool x)`, It calls the function just like I need. Now, how can I pass `Action<bool>` as completion to `UIView.Animate` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was an *old* binding bug (wrong type) and, for compatibility reason, `Animate` still use a `NSAction` completion handler.

To fix this a new method `AnimateNotify` was added to MonoTouch. This version accept a `UICompletionHandler` which is defined like this:

```
public delegate void UICompletionHandler (bool finished);
```

So the solution to your problem is to use the newer `AnimateNotify` API.

Comment: Don't you think it's time to remove old wrapper?

Comment: @Maxim: I imagine it would be overkill to remove it overnight. But obsoleting it sounds like a good idea to me. (I'm not a MT dev, just a user.)

Answer (score 5):

So that should look like:

```
UIView.AnimateNotify(duration, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, delegate () {

}, delegate (bool finished) {

});
```

Or with lambda syntax:

```
UIView.AnimateNotify(duration, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, () => {

}, (finished) => {

});
```